# How to change the rotation direction and to decrease the rotation speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ballPrefab;
    public int numberOfBalls = 10;
    public float fallSpeed = 5;
    public float spawningSpeed = 1;
    public float ballSize = 1f;
    public bool randomSize = false;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ballCountText; // Reference to the TextMeshPro Text
    public float maxRotationSpeed = 180.0f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10.0f; // Initial rotation speed (when it starts)
    public float timeToReachMaxSpeed = 30.0f; // Time in seconds to reach maximum rotation speed
    public float currentRotationSpeed; // Variable to display the current rotation speed in the inspector

    private int ballCount; // Counter for the number of balls
    private Transform cameraTransform;
    private bool changeDir = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        currentRotationSpeed = rotationSpeed; // Initialize currentRotationSpeed
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBalls());
        StartCoroutine(StartCameraRotation());
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnBalls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++)
        {
            GameObject ball = Instantiate(ballPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            if (randomSize)
            {
                float randomScale = Random.Range(0.5f, 2.0f); // Random size between 0.5 and 2
                ball.transform.localScale = new Vector3(randomScale, randomScale, randomScale);
            }
            else
            {
                ball.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ballSize, ballSize, ballSize);
            }

            Rigidbody rb = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.velocity = Vector3.down * fallSpeed;

            // Randomize bouncing direction
            Vector3 randomDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), 0, Random.Range(-1f, 1f)).normalized;
            rb.AddForce(randomDirection * 5f, ForceMode.Impulse);

            // Increase the ball count and update the TextMeshPro Text
            ballCount++;
            ballCountText.text = "Balls: " + ballCount;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawningSpeed); // Time delay between spawning balls
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator StartCameraRotation()
    {
        float timer = 0.0f;

        while (timer < timeToReachMaxSpeed)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            currentRotationSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(0, maxRotationSpeed, timer / timeToReachMaxSpeed);

            // Rotate the camera around the target
            cameraTransform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up, currentRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            yield return null;
        }

        // Now, keep rotating at the maximum speed
        while (true)
        {
            cameraTransform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up, maxRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // If it's time to change direction
            if (changeDir == false)
            {
                // Reset the timer and reverse the rotation direction
                timer -= Time.deltaTime;
                maxRotationSpeed = maxRotationSpeed - 0.1f;
                
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

At the bottom inside the while(true) part I want that when the camera is reaching to the maxRotationSpeed it will smoothly change the rotation direction and slowly slow down to 0.

what it does now when it's reaching to the maxRotationSpeed it's slowly decreasing the speed to 0 but then when it's getting under 0 to minus values then it's changing direction but also then increasing the speed.

I want it to change direction smoothly when reaching to the maxRotationSpeed and also start to change direction and when reaching to rotation speed 0 to stop the rotation also smoothly slowly.

Answer (score 0):

changedir is set to be always false is that normal?